# how to declare the variable and how to use substring

Tags: javascript

```
var myCountry="india";

console.log( myCountry);

myCountry.substring(0,3)

console.log( myCountry);
```

Here I have Declare a variable myCountry.I had give value as india.Used console.log to print the variable.Used console.log to print out the first three letters of myCountry.
error throwing by compiler is didn't log the length of myCountry to the console.

Answer (score 2):

`substring` doesn't alter the original variable, it returns the result back, so do:

```
myCountry = myCountry.substring(0, 3);
console.log(myCountry);  // "ind"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
myCountry = myCountry.substring(0,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: The substring() method does not change the original string.

```
myCountry = myCountry.substring(0,3);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp